# Which is best for performance

Tags: c#, performance

Can anyone shed some light on this for me.
Which would be better for performance

```
    foreach (DataRow row in prodStockLevels.Rows)
    {
       string stock = row["stpt_Stock"].ToString();
       textbox.text = stock;
    }
```

or

```
    foreach (DataRow row in prodStockLevels.Rows)
    {
       textbox.text = row["stpt_Stock"].ToString();
    }
```

Would there be much difference even if the datatable is huge. Just want to know is it better for performance if the data is passed directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There'll be no discernable difference in efficiency - I doubt that it's even *measurable*, if it exists *at all*.

The fact that you're assigning to a local variable will basically be irrelevant. The value of the expression `row["stpt_Stock"].ToString()` will end up on the stack either way. The only difference is whether that stack slot has a name or not.

In the debugger it might make a tiny but just-about measurable difference as it may have some additional implications - but *certainly* not enough to worry about.

I think I'd be more worried about the fact that you're repeatedly assigning values to the same `textBox.Text` property - only the last one is actually going to be relevant. You'd be better off just fetching the *last* row...

Comment: Thanks Jon, This is great. I was only using the textbox as an example, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

No difference. Probably the exact same code after compilation.

Answer (score 1):

No difference.
The following will be faster than both:

```
 textbox.text = prodStockLevels.Rows.Last()["stpt_Stock"].ToString();
```

Comment: _might_ be faster than both. The optimizer can see that the assigned value is never used and skip the assignment entirely. Not saying that it is but that it could

Comment: @Rune: An optimizer that eliminates assignments to a property will make a mess. And the Text property does trigger some logic and repainting.

Comment: If indeed there's side effects then the optimizer will not be able to removed the assignments but then your code won't work either since that's exactly what you've just done to optimize anyways